# Cursor disappears while debugging in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I enter debugging mode in Visual Studio 2015, and enter text into a text-box, my cursor (the arrow) disappears. It comes back immediately when I move the mouse with the touch-pad, but it is a bit annoying. Anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening and how to fix it? Is it actually a problem, or meant to do that?

I am running Windows 10, and this problem occurs nowhere else, only in Visual Studio.

Thankyou in advance,
Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have the "Hide pointer while typing" setting in the Windows Mouse Properties enabled:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou Lennart, I did have "Hide pointer while typing" checked, but even when I un-check it, the pointer disappears. I have closed and re-opened Visual Studio, and refreshed the computer.

Comment: Unfortunately you seem to be out of luck then: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759387/hide-pointer-while-typing-ignored-by-visual-studio